# How to pass user id in form

Tags: yii2

I have created a table called posts and linked the posts table to the user table with a author_id foreign key.

I have also created a controller, model and crud for the posts page.

In the posts page I would like to have the user id passed in the form in the _form.php view file automatically without inputting it myself by hand. How to do this please?

All I am trying to do is get the user id inside the form so it is stored in the grid for that user.

Here is the _form.php code:

```html
<?php


use yii\helpers\Html;

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */

/* @var $model frontend\models\Posts */

/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?>


<div class="posts-form">


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'posts_title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'posts_description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'author_id')->textInput() ?>


    <div class="form-group">

        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

    </div>


    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


</div>
```

Comment: You want set user id in author_id correct?

Comment: yas this what I want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller do this:

```
$model->author_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
```

If you want to user can't change author_id, you can remove element of `author_id`.

also you can do it in your view to set default of input.